# Subject Alternative Name is blank in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am creating a managed cert in Azure Key Vault but the Subject Alternative Name is blank. Any reason why?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am creating a managed cert in Azure Key Vault but the Subject Alternative Name is blank. Any reason why?

It seems that it is not supported now. And I also find an [issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/479) in the github.

I try to import the .pfx file to the keyvault and I capture the request with chrome browser. 
I find that it calls [import cert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importcertificate/importcertificate) rest api. there is no **sans**(Subject Alternative Name) property are returned in the [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/importcertificate/importcertificate#response).

[image]

You could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to Azure team, if you have any idea.